# Regular Expression Help / Little Understanding

Tags: c#

I am new to regular expression and am trying to create a form of syntax checking. When I use the code:

```
public Regex Injection = new Regex(@"(\w*\s*[,.()?':]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
public Match IdMatch;
public Match PassMatch;
```

To my knowledge this means that there can be any number or either words, spaces, or any of those characters in the string. The string I am trying to use, so

```
IdMatch = "001";
PassMatch = "123";
```

Then when this code is used:

```
if (IdMatch.Success || PassMatch.Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error, please try again");
        }
else
        { 
           // Continue code
        }
```

The error occurs. Why is this, are these strings violating the regular expression, or have I misunderstood something? Sorry if this is a simple question. Any help is appreciated, if I have been unclear please say so. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you assigning `IdMatch` and `PassMatch`?

Comment: `\w*\s*` means any number of words followed by any number of spaces. If you want any number of words or spaces, you'd need to do `[\w\s]*`. Expand that concept for the rest of the characters.

Comment: Just before the if statement. A button is clicked, they are immediately assigned, then the if statement occurs.

Comment: If you're concerned with your regex, you can test it on any number of regex-testing sites, like [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding changin to this:

```
String value1 = "001";
String value2 = "123";
public Regex reg1 = new Regex(value1, @"(\w*\s*\d+[,.()?':]*)");
public Regex reg2 = new Regex(value2, @"(\w*\s*\d+[,.()?':]*)");

if (reg1.Success || reg2.Success) ...
```